# Can the Windows 11 Clock App start a timer via command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-11, command-line-arguments

I have discovered that I can open the Timer page in the Clock app with this command:

`ms-clock:timer`

Can I start a timer automatically by passing other parameters? Something like this (hypothetically)

`ms-clock:timer 10m`

Comment: "The Alarm app settings are stored in \Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Alarms\ in the Alarms.json file (condensed JSON format)." See https://superuser.com/questions/1205323/can-the-alarm-clock-application-be-executed-via-command-line. You could have script to edit the JSON data.

Comment: Interesting. Not what I was hoping for, but thanks anyway @DrMoishePippik